# Prefilling a form field through url

Tags: python, django

I have a register form , in which when a already registered email gets entered , it shows a error message with a login link, when clicked on login link it redirects to login page, here I want to prefill the the email field with that user email. I am using django.

Does anyone know how to do it?
I would appreciate some help. Thank you.

my login url in urls.py:

```
path('login/', views.login, name="login")
```

my login link in error message:

```
<a href="login/">login</a>
```

Please let me what to do add to the link in url to prefill it with the user email ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to retrieve the data provided in the URL using [`request.GET`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET) and use it to prefill your [form's `initial`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values) in your login view. That would roughly look like this:

```
def login(request, *args, **kwargs):
    initial = {}
    if 'email' in request.GET:
        initial['email'] = request.GET['email']
    form = LoginForm(request.POST or None, initial=initial)
    ...
```

Of course you'll have to add the email to the login URL:

```
<a href="login/?email=foo@bar.baz">login</a>
```

Comment: any idea on how replace 'fool@bar.baz' into the email whatever user enters, in jquery